# Different error in Address function

Tags: function, excel-formula, count, row

I was originally building a formula to count how many cells were being filled in on a sheet different from the one that I was working on. I chose a set of blank cells on `Sheet1` with the following formula: 

`=COUNTA(ADDRESS(3,5,4,1,"Sheet1") & ":" & ADDRESS(4,12,4,1))`

The result was **1** for a set of blank cells. The equivalent formula -  `=COUNTA(Sheet1!E3:L4)` - returns the correct answer of **0**.

Why don't I get the same result?

---

Background: in the actual formula that I was using, I'd replaced the 3 & 4 in the `ADDRESS` function with a `ROW()` calculation to choose 2 rows at a time on `Sheet1` 1 row on `Sheet2`. I was testing the `ADDRESS` function for use by hardcoding the row addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`ADDRESS` creates a string, not an actual Cell Reference.  So, `=ADDRESS(3,5,4,1,"Sheet1")` is `="Sheet1!E3"`, not `=Sheet1!E3`.

To convert a String to a Cell Reference, use the `INDIRECT` function: `=INDIRECT("A1")` is the same as `=A1`.

Stick it together, and...

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,5,4,1,"Sheet1") & ":" & ADDRESS(4,12,4,1)))
```

(I *hope* you are going to change some of those 'magic numbers' to functions or cell-reference, otherwise you could just use `=COUNTA(Sheet1!E3:L4)` instead!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's much appreciated. However, from the documentation, you'd never know that ADDRESS creates a string, not the actual cell address. Oh, & I definitely was changing some of those 'magic numbers'! I found a different way to do it that was simpler.